# Problem with Swagger form to filter property

Tags: c#, forms, swagger

I created a controller (see below) in order to select my file, however in the swagger the form shows me the fields of user but in addition the content of cv and and one more time the  user referenced in cv.
I did a [JsonIgnore] but it doesn't work on the form it is impossible to validate it. So I created an attribute, an IOperationFilter and an ISchemaFilter to filter my swagger but there is a problem. The fields are well hidden but the form cannot be validated due to constraints on the CV fields such as [required]

Do you have an idea

ps: if we are on json and not in a form it works perfectly.

Controller :

```
[HttpPost("Action")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Utilisateur>> PostUtilisateur([FromForm] Utilisateur utilisateur)
```

Class :

```
public class Utilisateur
    {
        public int? UtilisateurID { get; set; }
        
        public string Nom { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="La photo est obligatoire.")]

        [NotMapped]
        public IFormFile Image { get; set; } 
        public string? URLImage { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public ICollection<Cotisation>? Cotisations { get; set; }

        public int? CVID { get; set; }

        public CV? CV { get; set; }
}

public class CV
    {
        public int? CVId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Le titre est obligatoire.")]
        [MinLength(10,ErrorMessage ="Le titre doit faire au moins 10 caractères.")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Le titre doit faire au moins 50 caractères.")]
        public string Titre { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "La Formation est obligatoire")]
        [MinLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Le titre doit faire au moins 15 caractères.")]
        [MaxLength(2000, ErrorMessage = "Le titre doit avoir au plus 2000 caractères.")]
        public string Formations { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        

        public int DomaineID { get; set; }
        public Domaine? Domaine { get; set; }

        public int UtilisateurID { get; set; }
        public Utilisateur? Utilisateur { get; set; }
        
        public ICollection<Candidature>? Candidatures { get; set; }

    }

public class IgnorePropertyFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        

        public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            var ignoredProperties = context.MethodInfo.GetParameters()
                .SelectMany(p => p.ParameterType.GetProperties()
                .Where(prop => prop.GetCustomAttribute<SwaggerIgnoreAttribute>() != null))
                .ToList();

            if (!ignoredProperties.Any()) return;

            
            foreach (var property in ignoredProperties)
            {
               
                var test = operation.RequestBody.Content.Values.ElementAt(0).Schema.Properties.Where(a => a.Key.StartsWith(property.Name + ".")).Union(operation.RequestBody.Content.Values.ElementAt(0).Schema.Properties.Where(a => a.Key == property.Name)).ToList();
                
                foreach (var element in test)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(element.Key);
                    operation.RequestBody.Content.Values.ElementAt(0).Schema.Properties.Remove(element);
                }
            }
        }

public class SwaggerIgnoreFilter : ISchemaFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
        {
            if (schema?.Properties?.IsNullOrEmpty() ?? true)
            {
                return;
            }
 

            var skipProperties = context.Type.GetProperties().Where(t => t.GetCustomAttribute<SwaggerIgnoreAttribute>() != null);

            foreach (var skipProperty in skipProperties)
            {
                var propertyToSkip = schema.Properties.Keys.SingleOrDefault(x => string.Equals(x, skipProperty.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

                if (propertyToSkip != null)
                {
                    schema.Properties.Remove(propertyToSkip);
                }
            }

        }
```